# How to use Python to get mathematical expressions in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software

I'd like to get the metric tensor that describes a non-rotating, uncharged, perfectly spherical black hole whose radius grows with time (it gains mass). For now, I have:

$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
-c^2\left(1-\dfrac{2GMa}{c^2r}\right) & A & B & C
\\
A & a^2\left(1-\dfrac{2GMa}{c^2r}\right)^{-1} & 0 & 0
\\
B & 0 & a^2r^2 & 0
\\
C & 0 & 0 & a^2r^2\sin^2{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}$

$a$ is the scale factor of the radius of the black hole. $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the unkown functions I'm trying to find. It must resemble Schwarzschild solution when $a=1$ and FLRW metric at infinity, so all three functions would go to zero when $a=1$ and when $r\,\to\,\infty$. Therefore, all three are $t$ and $r$ dependent and $\propto \left(a-1\right)/r$. Of course, that's because we are scaling black hole's radius by the FLRW scale factor $a$.

I'm doing the calculations by hand to get the Ricci tensor, but it is a lot. Is there a Python library or some tool that lets you compute/simplify these formulas? One that would basically operate and rearrange variables and parameters in such a way that you can rapidly find the three $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Gravipy is exactly what you're looking for: https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~hanauske/VARTC/VARTCorona/python/GraviPy-tutorial.html

Comment: You might be interested in SageManifolds package https://sagemanifolds.obspm.fr/ which is part of SageMath.

Comment: A black hole cannot become more massive with time unless it is absorbing something. The solution for a spherically symmetric uncharged black hole absorbing (or emitting) dust is the [Vaidya metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaidya_metric).

Comment: I found https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/diffgeom.html quite usefull. In particular the functions `metric_to_Christoffel`, `metric_to_Riemann_components`, `metric_to_Ricci_componenst`.