# Does $u$ depend on $r$? (Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates)

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

For ingoing Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates, we have that $t$ is replaced by $u$, which is constructed using both $t$ and $r$. By doing some calculations in which I'm trying to find the [components of this metric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/770126/how-to-use-python-to-get-mathematical-expressions-in-general-relativity), I arrived at:

$\Lambda=\dfrac{2\dot\alpha\left(u\right)}{r\alpha\left(u\right)}$

Where $\dot\alpha$ is the partial derivative of $\alpha$ with respect to $u$ and $\alpha$ is some unknown function with $\alpha\ge1$ and $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial u}\neq0$ (the function is a smooth, not constant one). The problem is that I arrived at this formula equating $R_{\mu\nu}=\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$.

Now, I currently cannot find the way to justify that $\dfrac{2\dot\alpha\left(u\right)}{r\alpha\left(u\right)}$ is a constant for every $u$ and $r$. If that was the case then:

1. The function $\alpha$ should be dependent on $r$ and not only on $u$.
2. The equation only applies to certain light beam trajectories in which the equality holds.

The problem with the first option is that if $\alpha$ is also dependent on radius then the partial derivatives with respect to $r$ are not zero. And that creates an incompatible system of equations, which sets $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial r}=0$ somewhere, which is a contradiction. Therefore, the only way I can think of the equation making sense is by considering a trajectory such that values of $u$ cancel with the $\dfrac{1}{r}$.

**The question:** Is this last option acceptable? Can the function be dependent on $r$ indirectly through $u$ and having $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial r}=0$? Or the only right path to follow is considering the metric inconsistent with this configuration of eqs.?